# Why do some Steam game achievements not show on the Achievement Showcase?

Tags: steam, achievements, lovers-smiles

I've bought a game on Steam and completed 100% of the achievements for it a few months ago. However, I recently noticed that the number of achievements and perfect games hasn't updated on the 'Achievement Showcase' of my profile.

My best guess would be that this is due to the fact that the game in question (*[Lovers' Smiles](https://store.steampowered.com/app/956100/Lovers__Smiles/)*) has a huge number of achievements compared to the amount of time it took me to complete them (100 achievements for barely 2 hours of playtime).

Why are some games excluded from the achievement showcase? Why do some games have achievements at all if they are not going to count towards the Achievement Showcase? Is there any way to tell before purchase if a game is in that situation?

Comment: If you visit [game page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/956100) you will see there "Profile Features Limited" in game features (on the right side, scroll down a bit, where it say "Single-player", "Steam Achievements", etc.). This will limit what games can offer. I myself experienced this issue with steam cards, where game promises there are some, but I get none. Given enough time and popularity, this game may get "full" features I guess or, maybe, removed/banned (this I don't know), some old game I bought at some point will give cards, others - never.

Comment: Hi @Sinatr - that's useful information - in future, it would be better if it were in an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back on May 2017, [Steam restricted the ability of newly released games to drop Trading Cards](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1954971077935370845). Then on June 2018, [Valve decided to restrict more features from newly released games](https://twitter.com/SteamDB/status/1007532765670203392), this time the restrictions being:

- Limit the game's total number of achievements to 100
- The number of achievements won't count for the total number of achievements
- Achievements can't be shown on the Profile Showcase
- The game will not count for the total number of games and will not be shown in the Profile Showcase
- Will be ineligible for coupons

As per Valve's announcement, the games will be allowed to use this set of restricted features once the "confidence metric" goes up enough via player count and interaction. For the case of Lovers ' Smile, you can see that the game has a [low number of reviews](https://store.steampowered.com/app/956100/Lovers__Smiles/#app_reviews_hash) and a non existent [player count](https://steamcharts.com/app/956100), probably causing the game to never reach the "confidence metric".

As pointed out by Sinatr in the comments, you can see if the game has this set of features restricted by checking the features available in the game:

[image]

If the game has the restricted features enabled, the "Profile Features Limited" message will not appear:

[image]